# OS X timezone incorrect without internet connection

Tags: macos

After rebooting my macbook and my wifi is off, usually timezone changes randomly.

- I tried to uncheck the "Set date and time automatically" option
- Tried to uncheck the " Set time zone automatically "

Nothing helps, I want to set a default timezone/time to remember without internet connection

( can't really tell if its timezone-related but time/clock is always incorrect after boot without internet connection )

System Preferences shows this

[image: Sys Pref]

Comment: What does it show in System Preferences -> Date & Time ?

Comment: @Mark http://i.imgur.com/LWtSz5m.png

Answer (score 1):

Reset the PRAM, by holding the keys cmd-alt-P-R during startup. If the symprom does not go away, the PRAM battery is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Is your machine older than 4-5 years?.
Perhaps is the PRAM battery (holding the time settings) out of power.

Comment: its 2013 Macbook Air.